# Alter Column from a date to accept systimestamp

Tags: sql, oracle, alter, systimestamp

At the current time I have a trigger that updates a date field with `sysdate`, unfortunately this can sometimes not be unique if an update occurs within the same second. Is it possible to alter a column to use `systimestamp` so that it using milliseconds and will always be unique.

The triger looks like this:

```
BEGIN
IF INSERTING or :old.STATUS_FLAG <> :new.STATUS_FLAG THEN
INSERT INTO T_SCHEME_STATUS_HISTORY
  (SCHEME_ID, STATUS_FLAG, DATE_STATUS_CHANGED, AUDIT_CREDENTIALS, AUDIT_DTM)
VALUES
  (:new.SCHEME_ID, :new.STATUS_FLAG, sysdate, :new.AUDIT_CREDENTIALS, SYSDATE);
END IF;  
END;
```

I want to change the `DATE_STATUS CHANGED` to use `systimestamp` so it is always unqiue but the column it is updating is of type `DATE(7)` so it won't fit.

Is there a way of altering the table to accept `systimestamp`?
Let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: Using a DATE or a TIMESTAMP field as a primary or unique key is not a good idea. Just because you decrease the chances of collisions by using a TIMESTAMP, you don't remove the likelihood that there won't be any.

Comment: the issue i have is that this code is legacy and I am trying to find a solution to the problem. I would have loved to design the code a completely different way but now I have to deal with what's there.

Comment: You can't add another column, add a sequence which you use to populate the new column, and then switch the unique constraint to reference the sequence column? You could even add a trigger to do the population of the new column, if you're not able to amend the code to handle the insert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Boneist's remarks about not using time values as keys are spot on. HOWEVER, if you're absolutely bound and determined to do this - yeah, sure, it can be done:

```
ALTER TABLE WHATEVER
  MODIFY (SOME_DATE_FIELD TIMESTAMP(6));
```

This changes the data type to a TIMESTAMP(6), which is accurate down to 1/1,000,000 of a second. Hopefully this will satisfy your requirement, but really - date/time fields should never be used as a unique key.

Best of luck.